# FOR looping while grabbing part of the data from $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop

It has been awhile since I have messed with for loops and was wondering if this is possible:
Here is what I have:

```
$mn = $_POST['mnpoints'];                   
$mi = $_POST['mipoints'];
$in = $_POST['inpoints'];
$wi = $_POST['wipoints'];
```

These grab numbers from a form once the submit button is clicked it will the use the following code to update the MySQL database

```
for ($i = 0; $i <=4; $i++ )
{
  mysql_query("UPDATE " . $db_table . " SET `score` = `score` + <VARIABLE HERE> WHERE id=$i") or die (mysql_error());
}
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I can always change the variables to be $m1 - $m4 and the just use $m$i

Just wondering if there is another way or a better way
Thanks

Comment: Put them into an array.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: `dies` is not a valid method. Please don't use `mysql_query` unless you have an exceptionally good reason. It's being retired because it is extremely dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Put your variables into an array:

```
$values = array($mn, $mi, $in, $wi);
```

Then iterate over it using `foreach`, or index it using `$i`.

**Note:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. I strongly suggest you read up on *mysqli*, *prepared statements* etc.:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

The mysql interface is officially **deprecated** and should not be used anymore.

Comment: Alternatively use foreach on the array vs for

Comment: thanks really new to php and sql will take a look and give it a shot thanks for the input

Answer (score -1):

How does 'mnpoints' and 'inpoints' etc... relate to "score"?If you're just looking at dumping all those values and adding them togetherm, then:

```
$score = $mn + $mi  + $in +  $wi;
$sql = "UPDATE ... SET score=score+$score";
```

Comment: it's pulling the data from a form then stores the value in the $mn $mi $in etc

Answer (score -2):

```
function bulkUpdateSingleColumn($table, $id_column, $update_column, array &$idstovals){
    $sql = "update $table set $update_column = CASE $id_column ";
    foreach($idstovals as $id=>$val){
        $sql .= " WHEN '$id' THEN '$val' \n";
    }
    $sql .= " END
    WHERE $id_column in (" . implode(',', array_keys($idstovals)) . ")";
//debugging info
    echo '<small>'.$sql.'</small>';
    $idstovals=array();       
    db_query($sql);      
    done();       
}
```

Comment: If you can't be bothered to [escape your SQL properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php) this is not a valid answer.